# WebKit on tap transparency not working

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am trying to get rid of the transparency on tap. But for some reason this doesn't work on any of the elements on my html document. Does someone have any idea why this might be?

```
body {
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba (0,0,0,0);
     }
```

Comment: as an experiment, try `*` instead of `body`

Comment: Still nothing. Its very odd.
It doesn't apply to submission forms or anything else.

Comment: do you mind making a fiddle for me? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uXL5W/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use 'html' instead of 'body'. That might fix your problem.

Comment: OK great. I'd still this though: `body, html { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba (0,0,0,0); }`